# Miles away tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a `UILabel` in a table view cell that I need to display the miles away between two coordinates constantly. I have two coordinates (a latitude and longitude). Now it successfully displays the miles away between the two coordinates but how can I constantly update the `UILabel` as the person moves without constantly refreshing the table view?

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.object = object
    let currentLocation = CLLocation()
    locManager.distanceFilter = 50
    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways){
        let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(-41)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(52.3)!)
        let coordinate₁ = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁)
        if(distanceInMeters <= 1609)
        {
            cell.Distance.text = "\(Float(round(distanceInMeters * 3.28084)).cleanValue) ft"
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Distance.text = "\(Float(round(distanceInMeters / 1609)).cleanValue) mi"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload the entire `UITableView`, perhaps you can reload specific row of it?

`func reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

If you don't want do it this either, maybe you should consider taking this view out of `UITableView` altogether.

Comment: When i change my current location and reload the view, the miles away number doesn't change. what should i do

Comment: There could be several things that could be going wrong. Put a breakpoint in your calculation code. Verify that the function is called and the new calculation is indeed correct.